# Random Number with each newsletter send via direct_mail

Tags: typo3

I am using direct_mail 5.2.2, Is there any way to send random unique number with each Newsletter send? without extending any fields?

I have to send uniquecode with each newsletter send via directmail how can i achieve this?

Comment: you need to specify what for you need the number. you probably want the number to identify, so aside from the usage in the newsletter you need to store the number somewhere. that usage should be clear beefore a solution can be considered.

Comment: Hello Bernd Wilke πφ
Thanks for reply, The newsletter I want to send is like a promotional pamphlet letting shortlisted guests know they can get a gift. However, so that i do not have people printing multiple copies of the newsletter to claim the gift, we want to number it so that each participant carrying that newsletter only can receive 1 gift from us

Answer (score 0):

Somehow use the id of the database row containing the receiver - in that way you have a unique identifier. Perhaps hash it before sending

Comment: problem: for the newsletter next month the same "unique" number is used.

Comment: Then use the id of the newly created newsletter entry as a hash parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the complete workflow of your usage, but here some thoughts which might need to be considered:

first of all: **hashes do not need to be unique!**
If you use hashes verify the uniqueness. This needs a list of all used unique ids.

based on Sorens answer I considered the following a unique IDs:

- <id of newsletter>-<id of recipient>
- <id of recipient>-<timestamp>
- <id of newsletter>-<id of recipient>-<timestamp>

To avoid misuse (printing a newsletter twice or printing a newsletter with a faked id) you need to store the generated IDs and notify any usage.
In that case you can obfuscate the ID with a hash. On hash collision just regenerate the hash with an added random (or meanwhile changed timestamp) until you receive a unique one.

Another way to avoid faking might be the generating of an complex image with the key, so nobody can easily replace some characters.

All this include a complex logic which could be packed into an extension plugin which would be one of multiple CEs building the newsletter.